# Rails on Windows: Slow?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows

I am doing some initial testing for a Rails app which will be deployed on Windows, but the development server in a VirtualBox is painfully slow. I've never seen anything like this in Linux (but the server platform must be Windows), even in an identical virtual appliance.

Is Rails on Windows viable in terms of speed?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I on the other hand find it to be pretty stable, and don't have any kind of speed problems.

I've been using Rails with Windows and Linux (still to use it with Mac OSX), and have had exactly the same sort of response times.

I prefer to use it on Linux though, because of the terminal and all the Linux goodies, but am pretty happy to use it on Windows.

**Update:**

Thought it would be nice to complete saying I've used Rails both from a Windows Machine, and from a Linux Machine with a virtual windows install, and as previously stated, i had the same sort of response times.

Comment: There are many others reporting windows slowness.  Not sure this is an answer, since there's no repro.

Comment: And you've -1'd my answer from 8 years ago because the software has changed so much @Chloe?

Comment: @MarcosPlacona Yes because it's no longer relevant or accurate. `measure-command {rails -v}` (PowerShell) takes 58s, on SSD even. That's unacceptable. How did you know it was me as I did not appear to leave a comment?

Comment: @Chloe This is not how StackOverflow works, and for that reason, your comment was probably deleted by a moderator. You had left a comment here earlier. If you have a better answer, by all means, add it here. -1 an answer is not the way to fix it. And at the time, my answer obviously helped the OP.

Comment: @MarcosPlacona I'm pretty sure that's how StackOverflow works. Answers that solve the problem float to the top. Answers that don't solve the problem sink to the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried 18.6, 1.8.7 and 1.9.1 on Window, OS X and Linux.
I have found the response time using Windows to be longer than using either OS X or Linux (Webbrick and Mongrel). 
If I use Windows purely as a server, response time seems as OS X Linux, but much slower if I develop and render result using any browser whilst using the same computer.

Comment: Interesting. Not sure what to make of all this yet. Thanks!

Comment: Response time is much slower in development mode because Rails reloads all your controllers and models (in case they've changed) on every request.

Comment: @Gdeglin, slower yes, but slower than on MacOS or Linux? All development environments should be about the same.

Answer (score 1):

I started RoR programming in Windows and yes, the server is *really* slow.
It did not matter if Windows was running in a vbox or directly as the OS, the server was slow. 
I've tried several things to get it faster (one cpu core just for ruby, etc), but nothing really helped so I went to Linux as working was much faster. You just can't work with a good speed if you have to wait for a server response everytime.

Answer (score 1):

I've been developing rails in windows for three years and the performance has been fine actually. My setup is relatively powerful: Dual Core 3.0 GHz, 3 gigs of ram, and it outperforms my coworker's new macbook pros by 20-30%. (When running 1200 integration tests).

That said, I have has ruby crash randomly after moving to 1.9 so I would definitely not recommend running any production server using MRI on windows.

You should strongly consider switching to JRuby if you are going to host your site on windows. Many production rails applications run on JRuby, and it's performance great and does not vary much between platforms. Here's a list of some sites running JRuby: http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/SuccessStories, and the home page for it is: http://jruby.org/

Another option for local development (that I have used on occasion) is to run Rails inside of a CentOS VMWare instance. Though my experience has been that the performance has been about the same or slightly slower, in that environment. You may see a benefit if you run rails in a multithreaded state (instead of just launching script/server).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks... the last option is not feasible because the point of the app is 100% to access Windows shares directly, so a VMWare would defeat the purpose.

Comment: Yeah it sounds like JRuby really is the best option for you, especially if you are deploying to Windows. This will also allow you to use the Java database connectors instead of ruby's ones (Which are known to have problems on windows).

Microsoft has been working on getting their own .NET implementation of Ruby to run rails for some time, so you may want to keep an eye on their progress, but it seems that they still have a long way to go before it is ready.

Answer (score -1):

for a speedup you could try my loader speeder upper (helps rails run faster in doze): https://github.com/rdp/faster_require
Also checkout spork, which works no in doze, and jruby also works well.

Comment: Hmm, for Ruby 2.5.3, Rails 5.2.2 on a current project, `rake -T` went from 4.3m to 4.1m. That's *minutes*! Still unacceptable. Used the 'global install' in `rubygems.rb`.

Comment: Oh, and running it again took 11.3 minutes! So it actually makes things slower! PowerShell: `measure-command {start-process "rake" -argumentlist "-T" -wait}`

Answer (score -2):

*This answer dates back to 2012, so the solution (and syntax) below refers to Windows XP. Not sure if this also applies to other dated Windows versions like Seven or Vista, it might still be worth checking it...*

---

I found that on a Windows XP machine running out of HDD space, Rails performance is  heavily degraded when the OS automatic file compression is turned on (it is by default) it has already compressed a lot of files.

To fix that, first free up as much space as you can, and then decompress all the files that got automatically compressed by the OS with the following command:

> compact /u /s /i

(run it from the root dir, i.e. "C:\")

(just for the record, compressed files are marked in blue in Windows File Explorer)

In my case "rails -v" took 15 seconds before that, while after decompression (of some 54000 files...) it only took 2 seconds, as it initially did when I originally installed Ruby.